# TypeScript with UIAutomation (Apple's library)

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, typescript

I wonder if anyone has tried implementing [iOS UIAutomation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html) tests using Typescript.

I guess I will need to make my own declaration files and add them as needed however there is one thing I cannot figure out. Other javascript files need to be imported using the `#import` statement at the begging of sources. Something like this:

```
#import "File.js"

var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
target.logElementTree();
...
```

How can I deal with this syntax in Typescript? I thought of telling the compiler not to process `#import "File.js` just copy it into the result js but I couldn't find any compiler directives or alikes in the [specification](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf). Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to do this in Typescript. There is also an issue at [codeplex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/264). Until Microsoft comes around and adds directives, you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: I see. That issue was created last night by me after realizing there is no such feature. I hope they put in a milestone soon.

Answer (score 1):

I also did not find this feature in the documentation. I think there isn't a way to do this.

You can open an issue on codeplex requesting this approach.

Comment: Thanks ... i added an issue in [codeplex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/264) requesting this feature.